# Understanding why $(a^{-1})^{-1} = a$ in a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am looking at basic properties of groups, and one of them says:

Let $G$ be a group. For any $a \in G$, $(a^{-1})^{-1} = a$.

Observe that $a^{-1}(a^{-1})^{-1} = e$. Consequently, multiplying both sides of this equation by $a$, we have
$$(a^{-1})^{-1} = e(a^{-1})^{-1} = aa^{-1}(a^{-1})^{-1} = ae = a$$

So I am trying to figure out why they introduce the $a$ and then multiply both sides?

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We're trying to simplify $(a^{-1})^{-1}$. By definition, this is the thing that multiplied by $a^{-1}$ yields $e$, or in other words $a^{-1}(a^{-1})^{-1}=e$. In order to isolate $(a^{-1})^{-1}$ we need to get rid of the $a^{-1}$ in front of it, and the way to do that is to (left) multiply both sides by $a$.

That last thing really isn't anything new. In intermediate algebra, if e.g. we want to solve $\frac{1}{2}x=3$ for $x$, the thing to do would be to multiply both sides by $2$ (since $\frac{1}{2}$ and $2$ are inverses).

Comment: Aha that was pretty simple :-). Thank you.